# Connect router with other router in different routing protocol without redistribution

Tags: networking, eigrp

I'm running EIGRP (101 between r3,r4,r5 and all interfaces are added.  Now I want r1 and r2 to reach to server 12.0.0.1 connected to r5.  The server can't ping another PCs, but all PCs can ping 12.0.0.1. r3,r4,r5 are connected to the internet. I'm not redistributing.
[image]

Comment: Make sure that your server has a default gateway of 12.0.0.182 (router interface).  BTW, this question might be better asked on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Also check the firewall on your other PCs.  It may be blocking pings.

Comment: r3,r4,r5 are ISP like ADSL and I cant do any protocol in there

Comment: If PCs can ping 12.0.0.1, then you don't have a routing problem.  the problem is either firewall on PCs or default gateway on server.